# How can I get the total facebook friend list by using facebook SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I want users to invite facebook friends by using FBSDKAppInviteContent and FBSDKAppInviteDialog, but the Facebook friendList is not total.How can I get the total facebook friendList?

Comment: You can't. How to invite people to your app is explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191

Comment: Do you need all friend for logged in user or do you need those one who are using your application?

Comment: everything you need to know is in that duplicate answer

Answer (score 0):

You can't get all friend list on your facebook login account,b'coz of facebook terms and privacy, you can get friend who logged in your Application using facebook sdk, so you just get list only your application user list through facebook sdk.  for more info preferred below link

**[This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_104376946653191)**